# How to install Shan language on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, language-support, internationalization, translation

I'm from Myanmar. At our place we use [Shan Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shan_language) which is related to Thai.

How do I set-up my Ubuntu 12.04 so that I can read and write in my language?

Comment: I could not find any support for your language. I suggest you contact the [Ubuntu Myanmar LoCo Team](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/ubuntu-mm/) they should be in a position to tell you what support there is for Shan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching I found the following two packages:

1. [Tai/Shan for iBus my_SHN-ibus-1.4_keymagic_1.5-1_i386.deb](http://www.umunthu.net/downloads/my_SHN-ibus-1.4_keymagic_1.5-1_i386.deb) will allow you to add Tai languages (=Shan) to ibus.
2. [Tai/Shan fonts for Ubuntu Tai-Fonts-V2.0.0.deb](http://www.umunthu.net/downloads/Tai-Fonts-V2.0.0.deb) will allow you to read and write shan script

Unfortunately this doesn't solves your problem 100% because ibus doesn't work properly with this package. You can type, but the characters can't be recognised. To solve this problem you could edit the tai-sonla.mim and replace all the "ꪀ" with the right symbols. Maybe someone has a more elegant solutions for this last step.

[Keyboard mapping for Tai/Shan on iBus tai-sonla.mim](http://www.umunthu.net/downloads/tai-sonla.mim)

In the mean time you can also use the fonts in package [2](http://www.umunthu.net/downloads/Tai-Fonts-V2.0.0.deb) i.e. A Ying, Kaw Sai, Mongloi, Pang Long, Yunghkio, Tai,X 15-sslm, Ying Ying,Mone Harng Li,Khun jai, MM3 Shan to type shan in applications such as Word and Presentation.

How to install the packages and edit the .mim file:

**1 Enable iBus**

From Menu, System -> Administration -> Language Support
Under "Keyboard input method system" choose ibus

**2 Download all the files**

**3 Open the .deb packages and select "Install"**

**4 Edit the .mim file with**

sudo gedit /usr/share/m17n/tai-sonla.mim

Change all the "ꪀ" or "êª€" with the right tai/shan letters and save the file

You can for example copy them from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shan_language

**5 Add Tai languages i.e. "sonla-kbd" to iBus**

From menu, System -> Preferences -> IBus Preferences -> add input method: under the "Tai languages" category, choose "sonla-kbd".

**6 Test by opening Word**

Open word

Choose "Tai languages - sonla-kbd" by clicking on the keyboard symbol on the right top

If you edit the tai-sonla.mim, please share it again here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

currently it seems to be your language was not available here.

[image]

You better contact your LOCO team for the support on your Language. Here is the link for you  [local-language](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/local-language)